# file conversion with bash command

Tags: bash

I have many files in the same directory and want to convert them to another file in using a bash command(`.sam` to `.bam`). I wrote this small command in bash. it works fine but the problem is that all resulting files would have the same name and consequently replacing each other and at the end I would have only one file. do you know how I can change this command in such a way that I get `.bam` file for each `.sam` file separately?

```
BAM_OUTDIR="bam_files"
SAM_INDIR="sam_files"

ls -1 ${SAM_INDIR}/*.sam | while read file; do

    echo "conversion of sam to bam started ..................."
    dn=$(dirname "$file");
    output="${BAM_OUTDIR}/alignment.bam";
    samtools view -Sb "${file}" > "${output}"
done
```

Comment: I think you want to change the file extension. Conversation of a file is a different action (means change the data structure)

Comment: I think the problem is here:     output="${BAM_OUTDIR}/alignment.bam";

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fimliar with bash, but for years an unix administrator gave me an example to change the linebreak in files (Unix to Win and vice versa):

```
 for i in `ls *.conf`
 do
   unix2dos <$i >$i.new
 done
```

So here a **hypothetical** way:

```
 for i in `ls ${SAM_INDIR}/*.sam`
 do
    samtools view -Sb <$i >${BAM_OUTDIR}/$i.bam
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this :

```
BAM_OUTDIR="bam_files"
SAM_INDIR="sam_files"

ls -1 ${SAM_INDIR}/*.sam | while read file; do

  echo "conversion of sam to bam started ..................."
  dn=$(dirname "$file");
  new_bn=$(basename "$file" | sed s%sam$%bam%);
  output="${BAM_OUTDIR}/$new_bn";
  samtools view -Sb "${file}" > "${output}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BAM_OUTDIR="bam_files"
SAM_INDIR="sam_files"
for file in $SAM_INDIR/*.sam; do 
    echo "conversion of sam to bam started ..................."
    base=$(basename $file); 
    samtools view -Sb "${file}" > "${BAM_OUTDIR}/${base%.sam}.bam"
done
```

Instead of parsing the output ls -- [don't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- this uses shell globs to iterate over all of the *.sam files in $SAM_INDIR. It then uses an intermediate variable `base` to hold the incoming filename, without the $SAM_INDIR part. The `samtools` command then redirects the output to a file in $BAM_OUTDIR, named by removing the ".sam" from the end of the base filename, then appending ".bam".